# How to print using bluetooth in UWP on windows 10 phone

Tags: printing, windows-10-universal, bluetooth-printing

I have followed this link to do printing in UWP.
[Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing)
this code working fine in windows desktop version of UWP.

but I am not getting Bluetooth printer when running this code on windows phone. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

On Universal Windows Platform, currently, the possible way is to use [POS printer API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt426652). It enables us to print to **network** and **Bluetooth** connected receipt printer.

The important thing is, the printer should use the **Epson ESC/POS** printer control language.

Please see [POS printer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PosPrinter)